# How can i make conference call In twilio by using @twilio/voice-sdk packege in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, twilio-twiml

Every time i try always Call disconnect.

I can able to make voice call  by
params = {
To: number,
From: "+XXXXXXXXXXXX",
}

const twilioCall = await device.connect({params});
But how can I Make Conference call.
I tryed
const twilioCall = await device.connect({To: `conference:${sessionIDD}`});
const twilioCall = await device.connect(params:{{To: `conference:${sessionIDD}`}});
const twilioCall = await device.connect({params:{conference:sessionIDD}});

But Every time i try Call disconnect

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.